# How to resolve JSP pages dynamicly from an external source like a database

Tags: jsp, dynamic, runtime, reload

Does anyone know how to setup/configure Tomcat's JSP engine to load JSP pages from an external source like a database or JCR?  The project that I'm working on uses groovy scripts, freemarker templates, etc that is loaded from a JCR at runtime (it is cached and reloaded when I update the JCR).  I also want to add JSP pages as an optional template/script alternative but I can't figure out how to load JSP dynamically at runtime when I update it in the JCR.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to save your JSP content from DB to a file in webapp directory and just hit a proper URL in a browser or possibly include this file to other JSP. 
You could also play around with filters and there generate those new JSP files on demand.